# Get the list of languages of an item in a droplist field query source

Tags: sitecore-query

As a source for a DropList, I would like to use a query that returns the list of languages defined for a specific item.
Is it possible?

Comment: Closing, unresolved and abandoned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

#### Not really

Not out of the box. Not in any way I could find at least.

Reason is; Sitecore Query (or even fast: query) works on item-level. I've never seen it used to query multiple versions of any single item, which is what you need here.

#### But with a little work

But there are options with a reasonably small code footprint. Alex Smagin (and others) wrote about, putting custom tokens into the datasource area of your field, to execute custom functionality.

[SITECORE: EXTENDING FIELD DATASOURCE QUERIES WITH TOKENS,](https://asmagin.com/2014/06/22/sitecore-extending-field-datasource-queries-with-tokens/)

Basically it involves hooking into Sitecore's `GetLookupSourceItems` pipeline and injecting the specific dropdown list options you need there.